# telling 'make' to ignore dependencies when the top target has been created

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm running the following kind of pipeline:

```
digestA: hugefileB hugefileC
    cat $^ > $@
    rm $^

hugefileB:
    touch $@

hugefileC:
    touch $@
```

The targets **hugefileB** and **hugefileC** are very big and take a long time to compute (and need the power of Make). But once **digestA** has been created, there is no need to keep its dependencies: it deletes those dependencies to free up disk space.

Now, if I invoke 'make' again, **hugefileB** and **hugefileC** will be rebuilt, whereas **digestA** is already ok.

Is there any way to tell 'make' to avoid to re-comile the dependencies ?

NOTE: I don't want to build the two dependencies inside the rules for 'digestA'.

Comment: You want to rebuild `digestA` only when it does not already exist, is that right?

Comment: @Beta "You want to rebuild digestA only when it does not already exist":  yes

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use ["intermediate files"](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Chained-Rules) feature of GNU Make:

> Intermediate files are remade using their rules just like all other files. But intermediate files are treated differently in two ways.
>
> The first difference is what happens if the intermediate file does not exist. If an ordinary file b does not exist, and make considers a target that depends on b, it invariably creates b and then updates the target from b. **But if b is an intermediate file, then make can leave well enough alone. It won't bother updating b, or the ultimate target, unless some prerequisite of b is newer than that target or there is some other reason to update that target.**
>
> The second difference is that if make does create b in order to update something else, it deletes b later on after it is no longer needed. **Therefore, an intermediate file which did not exist before make also does not exist after make.** make reports the deletion to you by printing a `rm -f` command showing which file it is deleting.
>
> Ordinarily, a file cannot be intermediate if it is mentioned in the makefile as a target or prerequisite. **However, you can explicitly mark a file as intermediate by listing it as a prerequisite of the special target `.INTERMEDIATE`.** This takes effect even if the file is mentioned explicitly in some other way.
>
> **You can prevent automatic deletion of an intermediate file by marking it as a secondary file.** To do this, list it as a prerequisite of the special target `.SECONDARY`. When a file is secondary, make will not create the file merely because it does not already exist, but make does not automatically delete the file. Marking a file as secondary also marks it as intermediate.

So, adding the following line to the Makefile should be enough:

```
.INTERMEDIATE : hugefileB hugefileC
```

Invoking make for the first time:

```
$ make
touch hugefileB
touch hugefileC
cat hugefileB hugefileC > digestA
rm hugefileB hugefileC
```

And the next time:

```
$ make
make: `digestA' is up to date.
```

Comment: many thanks. It is very helpful. Your solution was cited here: http://plindenbaum.blogspot.com/2012/08/next-generation-sequencing-gnu-make-and.html

Comment: Do you have some insight as to why .secondary isn't the default behavior for all targets?

Comment: @Pierre, hmm, sounds interesting, however after some thought I was unable to answer your question.

The only slightly related piece of the manual [says](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Targets): "`.SECONDARY` with no prerequisites causes all targets to be treated as secondary (i.e., no target is removed because it is considered intermediate)." But it does not tell anything about reasons behind the default behavior.

Answer (score 3):

If you mark `hugefileB` and `hugefileC` as [intermediate files](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Chained-Rules), you will get the behavior you want:

```
digestA: hugefileB hugefileC
        cat $^ > $@

hugefileB:
        touch $@

hugefileC:
        touch $@

.INTERMEDIATE: hugefileB hugefileC
```

For example:

```
$ gmake
touch hugefileB
touch hugefileC
cat hugefileB hugefileC > digestA
rm hugefileB hugefileC
$ gmake
gmake: `digestA' is up to date.
$ rm -f digestA
$ gmake
touch hugefileB
touch hugefileC
cat hugefileB hugefileC > digestA
rm hugefileB hugefileC
```

Note that you do not need the explicit `rm $^` command anymore -- gmake automatically deletes intermediate files at the end of the build.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to create pseudo-cache files that are created by the `hugefileB` and `hugeFileC` targets.

Then have `digestA` depend on those cache files, because you know they will not change again until you manually invoke the expensive targets.

Answer (score 1):

See also [.PRECIOUS](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html#index-_002ePRECIOUS):

```
.PRECIOUS : hugefileA hugefileB
```

> .PRECIOUS
>
> The targets which .PRECIOUS depends on are given the following special treatment: if make is killed or interrupted during the execution of their recipes, the target is not deleted. See Interrupting or Killing make. Also, if the target is an intermediate file, it will not be deleted after it is no longer needed, as is normally done. See Chains of Implicit Rules. In this latter respect it overlaps with the .SECONDARY special target.
>
> You can also list the target pattern of an implicit rule (such as ‘%.o’) as a prerequisite file of the special target .PRECIOUS to preserve intermediate files created by rules whose target patterns match that file’s name.

Edit: On re-reading the question, I see that you don't want to keep the hugefiles; maybe do this:

```
digestA : hugefileA hugefileB
    grep '^Subject:' %^ > $@
    for n in $^; do echo > $$n; done
    sleep 1; touch $@
```

It truncates the hugefiles after using them, then touches the output file a second later, just to ensure that the output is newer than the input and this rule won't run again until the empty hugefiles are removed.

Unfortunately, if only the digest is removed, then running this rule will create an empty digest.  You'd probably want to add code to block that.

Comment: It seems like `.SECONDARY: foo` is equivalent to setting both `.INTERMDIATE: foo` `.PRECIOUS: foo`. Is that right?

Comment: It would seem so, yes: this page on [chained rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html) says that .SECONDARY files are not deleted (like .PRECIOUS files), and are also marked as .INTERMEDIATE files (created when executing chained rules).  On [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html#index-_002ePRECIOUS) it says that .PRECIOUS overlaps with .SECONDARY, at least when applied to .INTERMEDIATE files.

Answer (score -2):

The correct way is to not delete the files, as that removes the information that `make` uses to determine whether to rebuild the files.

Recreating them as empty does not help because `make` will then assume that the empty files are fully built.

If there is a way to merge digests, then you could create one from each of the huge files, which is then kept, and the huge file automatically removed as it is an intermediate.

Comment: The Question specfically states that the asker does not wish to delete the files, due to their massive size. (P.S., I think from the fact that the asker says "I'm running the following kind of pipeline", that means that the code provided is just example code, and the asker is not actually just creating empty files.)